# How to edit mat cell data in angular

Tags: angular

I have 2 column in my mat table: Key and Value. I want to edit the value part after clicking on Edit button icon and console that after clicking on update button.

> html file

```
<div>
    <button mat-stroked-button class="b1" (click)="update()">Update</button>
    <h5>Request Details</h5>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="item-name"> {{element.key}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </td>

            <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" *ngIf="isValid">
                <input matInput placeholder="Value" [value]="element.value" [(ngModel)]="element.value">
            </mat-form-field>
        </ng-container>     



            <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                  <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to Edit" (click)="onCreateInput()" class="iconbutton" color="primary">
                      <mat-icon aria-label="Edit">edit</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>


        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

> ts file

```
isValid:boolean=false
  onCreateInput()
  {
    this.isValid=true;
  }
  update()
  {
    console.log("Hello")
  }
```

Comment: Could you show us a stackblitz or jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you disable the input instead of not render can be helpful, if this doesnt help you, maybe you can share a repo or stackblitz to help you to achive it

```
          <ng-container matColumnDef="value" >
           <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
           <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > 
             <span *ngIf="!element.editable; else editPlace">
              {{element.value}} 
             </span>
             <ng-template #editPlace>
               <input [(ngModel)]="element.value" 
                (keyup.enter)="element.editable = false" >
             </ng-template>
           </td>
          </ng-container>
```

And on your ts file:

```
   toggleValid() {
     this.isValid = !this.isValid;
   }
```

Could be work better than only assign to `true`

> edit

this will help with the complete 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifrzkl-bmsx3d?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: can you share the repo? I can check it out

Comment: Basically I recommend that you create another column so that you add the action buttons in it, because currently your button is out and when you click it does not know what element it has to enable, so if you add it within your row, you will do reference to each of the elements that are in the selected row